# How to prove that in another direction $\inf_x |f(x)|>0$?

Tags: real-analysis

[Bounded variation of $\frac1f$ when $\inf(|f|)>0$ & $f$ bounded variation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2541155/bounded-variation-of-frac1f-when-inff0-f-bounded-variation)

Let $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be bounded variation on $[a,b]$ with $f(x)\neq 0$ for all $x$. Show that $1/f$ is bounded variation if and only if $\inf_x |f(x)|>0$.

---

For one direction, assume that $\inf_x |f(x)|>0$, then say $|f(x)|\ge c>0$ for all $x$. Then for a partition $x_0<x_1<\dots<x_n$ of a interval $[a,b]$,
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n|1/f(x_j)-1/f(x_{j-1})|=\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{|f(x_j)-f(x_{j-1})|}{|f(x_j)f(x_{j-1})|}\le \frac{1}{c^2}\sum_{j=1}^n|f(x_j)-f(x_{j-1})|
$$

Take supremum for every partition and then the variation
$$
V(1/f, [a,b])\le  \frac{1}{c^2}V(f, [a,b])<\infty
$$

Does this part make sense?

Also, how to prove that in another direction?

Comment: Functions of bounded variation on $[a,b]$ are bounded, so $\frac  1f$ is bounded.

Comment: @geetha290krm So is $1/f$ bounded implies that $\inf |f|>0$?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: @geetha290krm So there is nothing to prove? Just use the fact that the bounded variation of $1/f$ implies $1/f$ is bounded. Then there is a constant $C>0$ so that $|1/f|<C$. So $|f|>1/C$. Hence, $\inf |f(x)|>1/C>0$?

Comment: Yes, this part is trivial.